# Pusher : Error code {4005}

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, pusher

## I am using laravel version 5.6.12 and Vuejs 2

**Full error is :**

> Pusher : Error : {"type":"WebSocketError","error": 
>   {"type":"PusherError","data":{"code":4005,"message":"Path not
>   found"}}} app.js:47801 Pusher : State changed : connecting ->
>   disconnected

this error show in console , when send event from https://dashboard.pusher.com/apps/489207/console/realtime_messages
to console.log

**bootstrap.js**

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

 window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

 window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
     cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
     encrypted: true
 });
```

**also in config/broadcasting.php add cluster in pusher configuration**

```
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'encrypted' => true,
            ],
        ],
```

**app.js**

```
mounted(){
      Echo.private('chat')

            .listen('ChatEvent',(e) => {
                console.log(e);

            });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

don't forget to add Your pusher configuration in .env file

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
```

also check the channels Route and in your event class you should implement 'ShouldBroadcast'

Comment: this content in previously added.